# How do I add a new site to Railo?

Tags: tomcat, railo

Since making my site accessible via a A-level DNS entry (ie: awesome.site.com, as opposed to www.site.com/awesome), my Railo pages now fail with an error similar to

> railo path "[/var/www/awesome/WEB-INF/railo]" is invalid

So far I've created the DNS A record and added the new awesome.site.com entry to `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`

What else do I need to do to get my CFML pages working again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in [Robert Zehnder's "Adding new sites to Railo demystified"](http://kisdigital.wordpress.com/2011/11/16/adding-new-sites-to-railo-demystified/), I needed to also add the new site to Railo's server.xml file:

```
  <Host name="awesome.site.com" appBase="webapps">
    <Context path="" docBase="/var/www/awesome/" />
  </Host>
```

It was also key to make sure the Railo user had permissions to `/var/www/awesome/` so that Railo could create the `WEB-INF` folder.